# How to get object in UserControl from another Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have **MainWindow**, **MenuControl**, **EditorControl** in my WPF App.

When I click the "Get Height" `Button` in `MenuControl`, I want to get the `StackPanel`'s `Height` in `EditorControl`.

How can I get the `StackPanel` object in `EditorControl`?

MenuControl.xaml:

```
<Button Content="Get Height" Click="GetStackPanelHeight_Click"/>
```

EditorControl.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="xxxx">
    <Label Context="test">
</StackPanel>
```

MenuControl.xaml.cs:

```
public void GetStackPanelHeight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tmp = xxxx.ActualHeight;       
}
```

can not access xxxx.AcutualHeight.

If I wrote below,tmp=0

```
var editorControl = new EditorControl();
var tmp = editorControl.xxxx.ActualHeight;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I think the correct way to do it is using MVVM patern and bindings. Then comunicate between the view models

Comment: `xxx` is local to `editorControl`. Maybe you should expose whatever value you need as a `DependencyProperty` of your user control.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest solutions is:
In `EditorControl` you can get the value of the `StackPanel`'s `ActualHeight`.

For example:
Pass the `StackPanel`'s `ActualHeight` value into a `DependencyProperty` inside the `EditorControl`.
When the `Button` in `MenuControl` is being pushed, read the value of that dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
public class FirstUserControl
{
    public delegate void PropertyChangedHandler(object obj);
    public static event PropertyChangedHandler StackPanelHeightChanged = delegate { };
    public void GetStackPanelHeight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Example: here I fire the function in the second UC
        var tmp = xxxx.ActualHeight; 
        StackPanelHeightChanged(tmp);
    }
}
```

-

```
public class SecondUserControl
{
    public SecondUserControl()
    {
        FirstUserControl.StackPanelHeightChanged+= OnStackPanelHeightChanged;
    }

    public void OnStackPanelHeightChanged(object obj)
    {
        //here obj is the Height of the StackPanel
    }

    //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks！
I changed "OnStackPanelHeightChanged"  to "StackPanelHeightChanged"  and it works!